# Ordenar array números (String) y alfabeticamente (Mayus,Minus)

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array de valores combinando números tipo string y texto con mayúsculas y minúsculas, pero no logro tener el resultado deseado.

Alguna sugerencia?

```
$array = array() { 
             "0",
             "000",
             "prueba2.0",
             "0000",
             "directorio",
             "12345",
             "Asd",
             "asd",
             "00",
             "Prueba",
             "imagenes",
             "123",
             "fonts" 
         } 

//Utilizo la función natcasesort para ordernar
natcasesort($array);

// Me devuelve lo siguiente
array(13) { 
    [0]=>  string(1)  "0" 
    [8]=>  string(2)  "00" 
    [3]=>  string(4)  "0000" 
    [1]=>  string(3)  "000" 
    [11]=> string(3)  "123" 
    [5]=>  string(5)  "12345" 
    [7]=>  string(3)  "asd" 
    [6]=>  string(3)  "Asd" 
    [4]=>  string(10) "directorio" 
    [12]=> string(5)  "fonts" 
    [10]=> string(8)  "imagenes" 
    [9]=>  string(6)  "Prueba" 
    [2]=>  string(9)  "prueba2.0" 
}
```

Comment: Y exactamente cual es el resultado que deseas?, podrías explicar mejor por favor

Comment: Una disculpa, el resultado esperado sería que respetara el ordenamiento numérico y el ordenamiento de mayúsculas y minúsculas, por ejmp, en el resultado debería quedar "000", "0000" y "Asd", "asd", al menos en esos dos no me respeta el ordenamiento